# How to get SVG elements and Divs into an image so the user can download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-processing, svg

I would like to know how to render SVG elements with divs into one image.

Example:

```
<div class="objects ui-droppable ui-sortable">
        <div class="b_s _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor _jsPlumb_connected" id="start_block">START</div> 

        <div class="b_1 block ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor _jsPlumb_connected" id="n_block4" title="test"><span>test</span></div>

        <div class="b_s _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor _jsPlumb_connected" id="end_block">STOP</div><div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 530px; top: 52px; background: transparent;"></div>

        <div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 529.5px; top: 82px; background: transparent;"></div>

        <svg style="position:absolute;left:519.5px;top:48px" width="20" height="38" pointer-events="none" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="_jsPlumb_connector"><path d="M 0.5 -1 L 0.5 31 M 1.5 30 L -0.75 30 M 0.25 31 L 0.25 -1 M 1.25 0 L -1 0 M 0 0 L 0 30 " transform="translate(9.999999999999998,4)" pointer-events="visibleStroke" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" fill="none" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" style="" stroke-width="2"></path><path pointer-events="all" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" d="M4.684274006738627e-16,32.650000000000006 L10.000000000000002,7.650000000000007 L1.4221210955098638e-15,17.075000000000006 L-9.999999999999998,7.650000000000005 L4.684274006738627e-16,32.650000000000006" class="" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" fill="rgb(7,152,216)" transform="translate(9.999999999999998,4)"></path></svg>

        <div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 529.5px; top: 126px; background: transparent;"></div>

        <div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 530px; top: 156px; background: transparent;"></div>

        <svg style="position:absolute;left:520px;top:122px" width="20" height="38" pointer-events="none" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="_jsPlumb_connector"><path d="M 0 -1 L 0 31 M -1 30 L 1.25 30 M 0.25 31 L 0.25 -1 M -0.75 0 L 1.5 0 M 0.5 0 L 0.5 30 " transform="translate(9.499999999999998,4)" pointer-events="visibleStroke" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" fill="none" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" style="" stroke-width="2"></path><path pointer-events="all" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" d="M0.5000000000000004,32.650000000000006 L10.500000000000002,7.650000000000007 L0.5000000000000014,17.075000000000006 L-9.499999999999998,7.650000000000005 L0.5000000000000004,32.650000000000006" class="" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" fill="rgb(7,152,216)" transform="translate(9.499999999999998,4)"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Current JS code:

```
$("#btnExp").click(function(){
            canvg();
            html2canvas($(".objects"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    theCanvas = canvas;
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                    // Convert and download as image 
                    Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                    $("body").append(canvas);

                   }
               });

        });
```

With the code above, every element gets rendered, but the picture is not right. [How elements get rendered](http://puu.sh/o62p2/915eaf9e90.png) , [how they should render](http://puu.sh/o6Xll/a2a26ce722.png).

Answer (score 0):

The most promising method is rendering a part of the DOM to a canvas. This canvas can be displayed as image and downloaded by the users. Or you could save the canvas as blob, but not all browsers support that, so additional libraries could be used.
More information :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Comment: Could you try to make a demo ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can save parent div to a canvas and then to image and download it by using js

```
<div id = "widget" class="objects ui-droppable ui-sortable">
    <div class="b_s _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor _jsPlumb_connected" id="start_block">START</div> 

    <div class="b_1 block ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor _jsPlumb_connected" id="n_block4" title="test"><span>test</span></div>

    <div class="b_s _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor _jsPlumb_connected" id="end_block">STOP</div><div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 530px; top: 52px; background: transparent;"></div>

    <div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 529.5px; top: 82px; background: transparent;"></div>

    <svg style="position:absolute;left:519.5px;top:48px" width="20" height="38" pointer-events="none" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="_jsPlumb_connector"><path d="M 0.5 -1 L 0.5 31 M 1.5 30 L -0.75 30 M 0.25 31 L 0.25 -1 M 1.25 0 L -1 0 M 0 0 L 0 30 " transform="translate(9.999999999999998,4)" pointer-events="visibleStroke" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" fill="none" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" style="" stroke-width="2"></path><path pointer-events="all" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" d="M4.684274006738627e-16,32.650000000000006 L10.000000000000002,7.650000000000007 L1.4221210955098638e-15,17.075000000000006 L-9.999999999999998,7.650000000000005 L4.684274006738627e-16,32.650000000000006" class="" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" fill="rgb(7,152,216)" transform="translate(9.999999999999998,4)"></path></svg>

    <div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 529.5px; top: 126px; background: transparent;"></div>

    <div class="_jsPlumb_endpoint _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="display: block; width: 10px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 530px; top: 156px; background: transparent;"></div>

    <svg style="position:absolute;left:520px;top:122px" width="20" height="38" pointer-events="none" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="_jsPlumb_connector"><path d="M 0 -1 L 0 31 M -1 30 L 1.25 30 M 0.25 31 L 0.25 -1 M -0.75 0 L 1.5 0 M 0.5 0 L 0.5 30 " transform="translate(9.499999999999998,4)" pointer-events="visibleStroke" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" fill="none" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" style="" stroke-width="2"></path><path pointer-events="all" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" d="M0.5000000000000004,32.650000000000006 L10.500000000000002,7.650000000000007 L0.5000000000000014,17.075000000000006 L-9.499999999999998,7.650000000000005 L0.5000000000000004,32.650000000000006" class="" stroke="rgb(7,152,216)" fill="rgb(7,152,216)" transform="translate(9.499999999999998,4)"></path></svg>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>

<div id="img-out"></div>
```

js:

```
$(function() { 
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);


          }
       });
    });
 });
```

it has dependency over jquery,[html2canvas.js](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js),[base64.js](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/base64.js),[canvas2image.js](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js)

I think this will work for you.

Comment: Doesn't want to render SVG elements. 
What it looks like: [screenshot1](http://puu.sh/o5IyB/f00a6a6356.png)
What it should look like: 
 [screenshot2](http://puu.sh/o5IB7/e21655e913.png)
As you can see the arrows aren't rendered :/ 
Here's the error I get: 
**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.**

Comment: what you can do is first you convert all svg to canvas by using canvg library and once svg's converted the above code will run with out any issues.it will be an two step process.

Comment: Code works... but it doesn't work as i want it to work. It renders like this: [link](http://puu.sh/o62p2/915eaf9e90.png)

Comment: there is one work around for this may work. you can merge all svg's in to one nested svg and then call canvag function.(you can merge them with the help of d3)

Comment: But won't merging dislocate the svgs?

Comment: if you have proper coordinates defined and transforms it will not effect thw svg.. but if you have done it with any other method than it may..

Comment: Could you make a demo with an example?